# Django view of reward points that heavily filters and sorts (many) database results

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, django

My page (even when it has no data) takes 10+ seconds to load. That's just too long, considering when you finally get to it there's no data. When it has data, it takes even longer.

Here is my view, which I'm guessing is the problem:

```py
class RewardPointsEarnedReport(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'admin/hr/reward_points_earned_report.html'

    @user_is_staff
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(RewardPointsEarnedReport, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RewardPointsEarnedReport, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        employees = get_active_users(self) #THIS FUNCTION IS NOT THE PROBLEM
        page = self.request.GET.get('page')

        report_list = RewardPointsEarned.objects.all().order_by('-date_earned')
        academic_terms = AcademicTermType.objects.all()
        point_types = RewardPointsType.objects.all()
        if page is None:
            page = 1
        try:
            header = point_types[int(page)-1]
        except:
            header = point_types[point_type_list.count()-1]
        reports_by_category = [report for report in report_list if report.reward_points_type == header]
        this_term = AcademicTerm.objects.get(date_start__lte=datetime.now(),date_end__gte=datetime.now())
        current_reports = [report for report in reports_by_category if report.date_earned > this_term.date_end and report.date_earned < this_term.date_start or 0]

        point_type_list = []
        for point_type in point_types:
            point_type_count = RewardPointsEarned.objects.filter(reward_points_type=point_type).filter(date_earned__gte=this_term.date_end).count()
            if point_type_count:
                point_type_list.append((point_type, point_type_count))
            else:
                point_type_list.append((point_type, 0))
        context['point_type_list'] = point_type_list
        context['current_reports'] = current_reports
        context['academic_terms'] = academic_terms
        context['this_term'] = this_term
        context['header'] = header
        return context
```

If anything else could be causing the problem, please let me know. If there's also nothing I can do let me know as well. I'm pretty stuck, and any help is appreciated!!

I was told to add more code so here is the html:

```html
{% extends "admin/hr/index.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load in_group %}

{% block active %}
<li><a href="{% url 'reports' %}">Reports</a><span class="divider">/</span></li>
<li class="active">Reward Points Earned</li>
{% endblock %}

<!-- Content -->
{% block content %}
{% if user|in_group:"aux-dept-urec-hr" or "aux-dept-urec-facilities-admins" or user.is_staff %}
<!-- HR -->
<div class="span4">
  <div class="dropdown" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Choose Term
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      <ul style="list-style:none;padding:3px;margin:0px;">
        {% for term in academic_terms %}
        {% if term == this_term.academic_term_type %}
        <li><strong><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'rewards_earned' %}">{{ term }}</a></strong></li>
        {% else %}
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'rewards_earned' %}">{{ term }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr class="alert-success">
        <th colspan="1">Point Type</th>
        <th colspan="1" style="align:center;">Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for point_type, point_type_count in point_type_list %}
      <tr>
        {% if header|stringformat:"s" == point_type.name %}
        <td><strong>
            <a href="{% url 'rewards_earned' %}?page={{ forloop.counter }}">{{ point_type }}</a>
          </strong></td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">{{ point_type_count }}</td>
        {% else %}
        <td>
          <a href="{% url 'rewards_earned' %}?page={{ forloop.counter }}">{{ point_type }}</a>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">{{ point_type_count }}</td>
        {% endif %}
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="span8">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr class="alert-info">
        <th>Employee</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Date Earned</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for report in current_reports %}
      <tr>
        <td><a href="/helm/hr/employee/{{ report.employee.pk }}">{{ report.employee }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ report.points_value }}</td>
        <td>{{ report.reward_points_type }}</td>
        <td>{{ report.date_earned }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% empty %}
      <tr>
        <td style="color: gray;" colspan="4">(None)</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

This view displays points earned by someone, and it's filterable by type.
Here is a picture of the view:
[image: picture of the view in the website]

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please follow the guidelines at [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and change your question title to state what your code is actually supposed to do. Apart from that your question might lack sufficient code context for a meaningful review, since reviewers are left to guess a lot, e.g. about all the other classes used in the code.

Comment: What is `TemplateView`? A lot of your code is using `super().function_that_may_be_slow()`. Given that we can't access what may be the slowdown it means that we can't really help you get what you want.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I'm using Django, template view is part of Django. So is it the functions that are making it slow most likely?

Comment: @Peilonrayz should I limit the results before I sift through them, that way I'm not doing it through all of them unnecessarily? I'm not sure if I can or not but that seems viable

Comment: @Peilonrayz also, im not accessing any other functions besides ```get_active_users(self)``` or ```.objects.all()```, all of the information should be right there

Comment: @AlexV what do you mean by "other classes" ? Why would they have any effect on this? The other views are their own separate thing, and the only "functions" that are called are ```get_active_users()``` which is relatively fast, and ```objects.all()``` which is also fast because it is part of Django for getting model objects

Comment: @AlexV well, I'd hope that if they thought that was the problem, they would say so. Also, there is plenty of other things that I can see as potentially a slow down, but I'm not sure and just thought I'd post it here to see if anything obvious popped out to the professionals. I guess nothing did then.

Comment: @AlexV I edit it to say that that function is fine. I know it is because it is used everywhere, and nothing else slows down but THIS particular view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out why it was so slow.

It was this:

```py
reports_by_category = [report for report in report_list if report.reward_points_type == header]
```

and/or

```py
current_reports = [report for report in reports_by_category if report.date_earned > this_term.date_end and report.date_earned < this_term.date_start or 0]
```

Instead, I filter the object directly; for example:

```py
reports = RewardPointsEarned.objects.filter(date_earned__gte=session.date_end).filter(date_earned__lte=session.date_start).filter(reward_points_type=category).order_by('-date_earned')
```

This is A LOT faster! Insanely big improvement ~